# How to import ag-grid themes in angular 6

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

How can I import ag-grid theme in angular 6 project?

I've upgraded the project from angular 4 to angular 6. I had been importing the ag-grid theme using angular.cli.json file. Apparently angular 6 doesn't support that. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to it. We have to import ag-grid css in angular.json file in the project:

```
        `"styles": [`
          `"node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css",'
          '"node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-theme-material.css"]`
```